# SharePoint -- GetXRequestDigest call is failing with 403

Tags: sharepoint-online, saml, request-digest

We are trying to connect Sharepoint online instance using SAML Authentication.
We are trying to create site using Rest API.
As we are using SAML authentication , we need to use /contextinfo to obtain request digest.
This was working absolutely fine , but not sure why it is throwing error 403 now.

Following is the request sample :

```
URL: https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo,
headers: {
Cookie: rtFa=xxxx;FedAuth=xxx;
Origin: yourdomain.sharepoint.com
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Need some help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Fiddler to check the `rtFa` and `FedAuth` to confirm whether the cookie correct.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for the the help, the API was working fine nearly 3 weeks ago, but it is failing now, need to confirm on one point: is there any changes from API Side, If yes then need help to resolve the same issue.